# Can't determine where umask is being changed

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, umask

On my RHEL system, my `/etc/login.defs` has the line `UMASK 077`.

I have one user who has a `.cshrc` which changes his umask to 022.

I also have a second user who **does not have** a .cshrc or .bashrc or any other settings file, so I would expect his umask to be 077, however when I su to him, his umask is in fact 022.

I can't seem to figure out where this umask is being changed. Are there any other common locations this could be occurring?

Comment: Which version of RHEL? What about `profile` (both `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`?

Comment: My `/etc/profile` has no umask call in it, and the user himself has no `~/.profile` file either. RHEL is 5.4

Comment: Ok, that's old. In newer utilities, `UMASK` from `login.defs` is not even considered for login via `su` or `login`, etc. (See `man login.defs`, section `CROSS REFERENCES`.)

Comment: What is ***your*** umask before you `su`?  Are you doing  `su ` *`username`*  or  `su ` **`- `** *`username`*?

Comment: Ok, found the culprit.  There was an `/etc/csh.login` script changing the umask.